# Voice over shortcut on MacOS Mojave not working

Tags: accessibility

I'm trying to test the accessibility of a page on my MacOS Mojave via Voice over.
I must be able to turn voice over on and off via the shortcut Command + F5.

But the shortcut doesn't work.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer to my question.

I had to go to System Preferences/Keyboard/Shortcuts/Accessibility
And activate the option **Turn Voice Over on or off**:

[image]

Now the shortcut **Cmd + F5** turns Voice Over on or off as expected.